# Android - Issue with View when set above another View while scrolling

Tags: android, layout, scroll, android-relativelayout

I've created a ScrollView with a RelativeLayout inside of it.  I have a TextView aligned at the bottom of the RelativeLayout using `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and a ImageView above the TextView using `"layout_above"`.  The layout works perfect when I am on a device where the display is large enough to not have to scroll up and down.  When I test it on devices where you need to scroll to see the ImageView and TextView the ImageView doesn't line up above the TextView.  Actually I haven't a clue where it goes because I can't see it anywhere.  It might be behind the TextView.  This also happens when I'm editing an EditText with the Soft Keyboard up, which causes the RelativeLayout to scroll.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: for relative layout you specify `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and then place the image view below it by `android:layout_below=""` and then the textview below the image view. I guess you might get it.

Comment: That does work, but I need the TextView to be pinned down to the bottom of the parent and the ImageView to be right on top of it.

Comment: I think you can do that by specifying the margins

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I tried setting the margins, but that created different alignment problems.  What I ended up doing was setting the bottom padding of the ImageView to the same height as the TextView and had the ImageView alignParentBottom="true".  This works perfect on all the different screen dimensions I've tried.  

Thanks for talking me through it!!!!